# JavaScript function reads parameter differently than I expected

Tags: javascript

I have 2 functions. I'm trying to pass a text value from `editTest()` into the function `populateEditTestTemplate(x)`. Right before I pass in the value, I am logging it. This log shows `"1"` in the console. When I log the value after it is passed into  `populateEditTestTemplate(x)`, the log shows `[object Text]`. Why is this?

```
editTestButton.onclick = function editTest() {
    console.log("editing test");

    if (getSelectedTestIds().length > 1)
    {
        alert("You can only edit one test at a time!");
    }
    else if (getSelectedTestIds().length < 1)
    {
        alert("Please select a test to edit!");
    }
    else
    {
        if (!isHidden("new-test-template")) {
            toggleHide("new-test-template");
            testInProgress = false;
        }

        if(testInProgress == false) {
            testInProgress = true;
            toggleHide("edit-test-template");
            selectedTestId = getSelectedTestIds()[0];
            console.log(selectedTestId); // <----ouputs "1" ***********************
            populateEditTestTemplate(selectedTestId);
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
function populateEditTestTemplate(testId)
{
    console.log(testId); // <----ouputs [object Text] ***********************
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
        {
            var data = JSON.stringify(xhr.responseText);
            console.log("xhr response:   " + data);
        }
    }
    console.log(xhr.open("POST", "./db-queries/get-test.php",true));
    xhr.send("testId=" + testId);
}
```

Comment: trying doing `console.log(testId.data)`

Comment: Your `console.log()` statements may be confusing you. I find that it's **always** a good idea to include some identifying information, like `console.log("in populate, testId is " + testId);` so that you can tell one debug line from another.

Comment: Also it would be extremely helpful to see what `getSelectedTestIds()` does.